# Umbraco - How do I access a Content Blueprint (template) in code

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

So I know that I am able to obtain a content node with the following code:

```
Node contentNode = new Node(contentId);
```

I would like to access a content blueprint from within my code in a similar fashion, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I clearly didn't understand what a content template was, so thank you Claus for explaining this to me.

I did eventually find the solution to my problem. It turns out that content templates are also referred to as blueprints. You can obtain the content template (AKA blueprint) with the following code:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.Current;

// Obtain the Umbraco Content Service
var contentService = applicationContext.Services.ContentService;

// Obtain content template
var contentTemplate = contentService.GetBlueprintById(contentTemplateId);
```

If you then wanted to create a content node from this blueprint you could use:

```
// Create content node from content template
var content = contentService.CreateContentFromBlueprint(contentTemplate, "Content Node Name");

// Save and publish to new content node
Attempt<Umbraco.Core.Publishing.PublishStatus> publishStatus = contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(content);
```

Comment: Ahh .. yes - people refer to these things by different names. Often whenever someone mentions anything with templates - it's the actual templates they refer to, and not necessarily what they say ;)
We usually refer to the "content templates" as blueprints - as that's what they're named in code and that kinda avoids the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Content templates are simply `.cshtml` view files on disk. You can get the path of the view file for a template, using the `FileService` in the Umbraco API (it has methods for templates, partial views, scripts & stylesheets...). The `Name` property should have the filename including extension.

Then it's just a matter of editing the file if that is what you wanted to do.

The code editors in the backoffice are basically just getting and saving files from disk using the `CodeFileController` so you can have a look at that for inspiration if you have to do something similar.